# Specific URL for each kind of content

Tags: path-aliases

I would like each kind of content to have its own base url, for example, example.com/international-news/friendly-url-of-node-id

How can I manage to get both a friendly url and a base url (friendly-url... and ../international-news/ respectively in the example) with the minimum possible modules (or only those from the core)?

Answer (score 8):

Use [Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) Module to achieve it. It also supports **multilingual** functionality!!

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.

- Go to ***admin/config/search/path/patterns*** path :

[image]